# why the alert tag closes the jQuery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know why the alert tag closes jQuery dialog  and 
to stop that action.
Because the alert tag is opened the input text is wrong
and make user to insert correct information at the same dialog.
so the opened dialog should be opening while correct information is put.

1. click the "add" button

   ```
   $("#addButton").button({
       icons : {
           primary : "ui-icon-plusthick"
       },
       label : "Add"
   }).click(function(){
       $( "#addMemberDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
   ```
2. "add Member" dialog is opened and text boxes are empty. Then click the "submit" button. So the alert window is opened.
   ( The reason of true in "if" line is for testing. Later, I will replace this  line with inspecting  code whether text box is empty. )

   ```
   function addSubmitFunc(){
       var member = { "status" : "", "id" : "", "pw" : "", "address" : "", "tel" : "" };
       if(true){
           alert("complete the form");
       } else {
           member.id=$("#addID").val();
           member.pw=$("#addPW").val();
           member.address=$("#addADDRESS").val();
           member.tel=$("#addTEL").val();
           $.ajax({
               "url":"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/member/addAction.do",
               "cache":false,
               data:{"JSON":$.toJSON(member)},
               success:function(data){
                   createTableFunc();
               }
           })          
       }
   }
   ```
3. In alert window when click yes, the alert window closes and the "addMemberDialog" closes at the same time. I don't want to do that work

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What triggers `addSubmitFunc`? Sounds like page is navigating away.

Comment: `  $("#addSubmitButton").button({
   icons : {
    primary : "ui-icon-check"
   },
   label : "Submit"
  }).click(addSubmitFunc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*the "addMemberDialog" closes at the same time* - you think that it closes because the whole page is reloaded when the form is submitted. Return `false` from `addSubmitFunc` if you don't want the submision to go through, or make the button `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

Comment: Thanks return false works. one more, I used button tag <button> not <input type="button">. Can I use <button type="button"> or other property instead of return false?

Answer (score 0):

add `return:false;` after the alert box.

Comment: glad to know it help. :)

Comment: Sorry but What do you mean? Who's post?